# Can CAGR be calculated for a time periods less than 1 year?

Tags: stock-analysis, technical-analysis

I am using the CAGR formula to calculate CAGR of my full portfolio. But there are some stocks which were bought 6 months ago.
`cagr = ((end_value / buy_value) ** (1 / n)) - 1`
for eg if a stock was $50 6 months ago and now it is $100, its cagr comes out to 300% is that correct?

```
cagr = ((100/50) ** (1/0.5)) -1
cagr = ((2) ** (2)) -1
cagr = 4 - 1
cagr = 3
```

PS: `**` means power here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it back to first principles.

If it was $50 six months ago now, and is $100 now, it grew by 100% over 6 months.

If that rate is continued (HUGE "if"!), it would grow by another 100% in the second 6 months and be worth $200 after a year, growing by $150 for an annual growth rate of 300%.

So, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating [the internal rate of return (IRR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Internal_rate_of_return)

Starting the year with zero, $50 deposited after 6 months, $100 at year end.
[image: eq]

`∴ r = 300%`